# How to predict Uniqueness of a Title?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Right now I'm working on a project and came across a problem. I have a dataset(I cannot show the original dataset so here is a sample) as follows:

| Title | Uniqueness |
| --- | --- |
| Some title | 52.36 |
| Another title | 21.89 |
| One more title | 46.88 |

and so on...

The uniqueness here shows how much unique the given title is in the given dataset which is found using spacy. Also, Title contains unique values and Uniqueness contains float values.

My question is can anyone suggest me a good ML model that can take a string as input(Title) and predict its uniqueness.

Comment: Welcome to SoF; I believe that if you convert your categorical columns into numerical ones using [Category Encoders](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/), you can use any ML-based models. Check this [link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/08/types-of-categorical-data-encoding/), which could be a good start point and pick the best encoder that fits your context to transform. Of course, you should check that the way you choose would not be expensive computation-wisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem could be handled nicely using the Levenshtein distance metric. See

1. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
2. https://blog.paperspace.com/implementing-levenshtein-distance-word-autocomplete-autocorrect/